# How can I get all the user profiles in a site collection? (SharePoint Online O365)

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-jsom

How can I retrieve all the user profiles in a site collection with JSOM/CSOM or REST API ?

I find nothing that completely works, I need the following properties :

- Username
- Mobile
- E-mail
- Profile picture

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Microsoft Graph to retrieve all the users via the request below:

```
GET:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

You can get the username, mobile and E-mail via **DisplayName**, **mobilePhone**, **mail** property. And to get the profile picture, we need to send request like below for each user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value
```

And to call the Microsoft Graph REST API, we need to register the app and grant the suitable permission for the app.

The Scope for [List User](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list):

```
User.ReadBasic.All; User.Read.All; User.ReadWrite.All; Directory.Read.All; Directory.ReadWrite.All; Directory.AccessAsUser.All
```

The Scope for [get photo](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get):

```
User.Read; User.ReadBasic.All; User.Read.All; User.ReadWrite.All; User.Read
```

And since we need to get different users' profile, we need to use app-only token(Daemon service app).

Refer to [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) for calling Microsoft Graph in a service or daemon app

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to export all users to a file, use powershell. 
you need to change 2 things in the code below: locations of client libraries and site collection urtl.

```
    Add-Type -Path "c:\DLLS\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
    Add-Type -Path "c:\DLLS\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
    Add-Type -Path "c:\DLLS\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll" 

    #Mysite URL
    $site = 'https://NAME.sharepoint.com/'

    #Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

    #Authenticate
    $newCredentials = Get-Credential
    $UserName = $newCredentials.UserName
    $SecurePassword = $newCredentials.Password
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword) 
    $context.Credentials = $credentials 

    #Fetch the users in Site Collection
    $users = $context.Web.SiteUsers
    $context.Load($users)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()


    #Create an Object [People Manager] to retrieve profile information
    $people = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($context)
    $collection = @()

    Write-Host "Found" $users.Count " users. Exporting..."

    for($I = 1; $I -lt $users.Count; $I++ ){
        try
        {
            $percCompl = [Math]::Floor(($I / $users.Count) * 100)
            Write-Progress -Activity Updating -Status 'Progress->' -CurrentOperation "$percCompl% complete" -PercentComplete $percCompl;
            $user = $users[$I]
            $userprofile = $people.GetPropertiesFor($user.LoginName)
            $context.Load($userprofile)
            $context.ExecuteQuery()

            $profileData = "" | Select "FirstName", "LastName", "UserName",  "WorkEmail", "WorkPhone", "Department", "JobTitle", "Location", "SiteUrl"
            if($userprofile -ne $null -and $userprofile.Email -ne $null)
            {
                $upp = $userprofile.UserProfileProperties
                $profileData.FirstName = $upp.FirstName
                $profileData.LastName = $upp.LastName
                $profileData.UserName = $upp.UserName
                $profileData.WorkEmail = $upp.WorkEmail
                $profileData.WorkPhone = $upp.WorkPhone
                $profileData.Department = $upp.'SPS-Department'
                $profileData.JobTitle = $upp.'SPS-JobTitle'
                $profileData.Location = $upp.'SPS-Location'
                $profileData.SiteUrl = $site
                $collection += $profileData
            }
            else{
                $profileData.FirstName = $user.UserId
                $profileData.LastName = $upp.Title
                $profileData.WorkEmail = $user.Email
                $profileData.SiteUrl = $site
                $collection += $profileData
            }            
        }
        catch 
        {
            Write-Host "UserError: " $user.LoginName ". Error detail:" $($_)
        } 
    }

    $collection | Export-Csv C:\SPO-Users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor Green
```